# Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Symbol' and 'str' when forming a string with the factors of a number

Tags: sympy

I get this error. 
What am I doing wrong with the macro?

```
from sympy import *
var('y')
x=10
d=factorint(x)
print(d)
for k, v in d.items():
    y=y+str(k)+'^' +str(v)
print(y)

# {2: 1, 5: 1}
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "C:/xxx/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/soinsuu.py", line 9, in <module>
#     y=y+str(k)+'^' +str(v)
# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Symbol' and 'str'
#
# Process finished with exit code 1
```

i want

```
10=2^1+5^1
10=2**1+5**1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var('y')` is equivalent to `y = symbols('y')`, so `y` is a symbol. Then you do `y+str(k)`, adding a symbol and a string. That's a type error.

The type of `y` should be a string. And you want that string to begin with `10=`, so initialize it with that:

```
from sympy import *
x = 10
y = str(x) + '=' 
d = factorint(x)
print(d)
for k, v in d.items():
    y = y + str(k)+'^' +str(v)
print(y)
```

That said, you are missing the arithmetic operation... and it should be `*`, not `+`. 10 is definitely **not** equal to the sum of 2 and 5.

Also, Python has `join` string method for this purpose. Use it instead of a loop:

```
from sympy import *
x = 10
d = factorint(x)
y = str(x) + '=' + '*'.join([str(k)+'^' +str(v) for k, v in d.items()])
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def Myfactorint(x):
    return '+'.join([str(k)+'^' +str(v) for k, v in factorint(x).items()])
from sympy import *
x=10
print(x,'=',  factorint(x))
print(x,'=',Myfactorint(x))
# 10 = {2: 1, 5: 1}
# 10 = 2^1+5^1
```